# jQuery .ajax() to change page load behavior from form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, constantcontact

I am dealing with polishing up an email list cull thing from a sign-up/enroll widget.

The client uses a large email marketing provider (CC) to maintain their mailing lists and to dispatch emails to their prospective customers.

Anyhow, I have the fancy schmancy sign up thing presenting properly and POSTing the required data to CC with the appropriate account info but being that I obviously didn't create CC, I can't change the way their scripting works once they successfully receive a sign-up.

At present, I am getting a default, unstyled, and completely incongruous, CC branded success page.  If I scripted this myself, I would send location headers to a more germane success page or I'd send back an object to pipe in the success message without page load.

I do not have access to this CC account from the inside, so i cannot get the API/Developer key.

Is there a way to arrest the header send back from CC and just process that 200 status without pushing a page reload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like post the same info your form posts using ajax, and then upon success redirect your current page to some success page of your design (or just display something saying all went well, welcome to the list).

So in short:

- Scrap the form data (might be able to
  use the .serialize() method in
  jquery).
- Post data to CC using $.ajax.
- Display pretty success message or
  redirect.

Comment: Good, simple suggestion.  I've been having one of those weeks where these sorts of solutions don't come to the fore.  e.g., I was doing everything I could to prevent event bubbling to a problem lightbox invocation from a nested ANCHOR when the solution was just to return false on the default action ;) hahaha  Thanks